# Custom learner for sklearn AdaboostClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

I'd like to use scikit-learn `AdaboostClassifier` differently from the original proposal:

1) I want to mix different types of weak-learners in one Adaboost classifier;

2) I want to use custom learner types, different from the default ones available in sklearn.

After some research, i've noticed that the custom learners must implement a weight sampling function but got nowhere from here. I'd like to know if it's a good idea to customize sklearn or if i'd rather create something from scratch (which will take a lot of time). Also, i wasn't able to find other libraries that provide Adaboost implementations (in python) for classification.

If customizing sklearn is the good way, i'd appreciate some guidance about where to start from (API documentation is not that clear).

ps: i am relatively new to this area, but unfortunately this is a task that was given to me and it's really frustrating that i can't find a way to accomplish it.